# Join statement for intersection table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, intersection

I'd like to connect a user to one or multiple cars. The tables look like this:

table_a

```
id     name
1      tom
2      max
```

table_b

```
id     car
1      car1
2      car2
3      car3
```

table_ab

```
id     id_a     id_b
1      1        1
2      1        2
3      2        1
```

Which is the correct select statement so that the result is like:

- tom has car1 and 2
- max has car1

I don't get it to work with `INNER JOIN`.. what is the correct statement?

Comment: Why you posting same question multiple times?

Comment: table `table_ab` doesn't need id, its primary key can be `(id_a, id_b)`

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the hint! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `name`,`car` FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_ab ab ON a.id = ab.id_a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON ab.id_b = b.id
```

PS: You can also do this without any joins, in some cases, its faster and cleaner.

```
SELECT `name`,`car` FROM table_a a,table_b b, table_ab ab
WHERE a.id = ab.id_a AND ab.id_b = b.id
```

In this case, DESCRIBE showed identical results, so either options will work for you.

Comment: How does anyone upvote an answer with commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your comment. The statement with commas was additional to my main answer. Keep in mind that for some people, especially students, would be nice to show them what's possible and available in mysql. Also, maybe some people are working with a stripped down version of mysql (maybe in embedded apps, wo knows). Knowledge is power :) Wish you great day

Comment: @OliverMGrech . . . Commas are never faster.  And not cleaner in the opinion of most people who know SQL.

Comment: I didn't say its faster nor cleaner in all cases, read my answer again, I clearly said DESCRIBE showed identical results for the OPs scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `join`s and aggregation:

```
select a.name, group_concat(car) as cars
from ab join
     a
     on a.id = ab.id_a join
     b
     on b.id = ab.id_b
group by a.id, a.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @xnryxzaqa . . . Any of the other answers are better than the one you selected.  I note that this was first.

Answer (score 0):

You need  two join

```
  select a.name, b.car
  from table_ab ab
  inner join  table_a a ON a.id = ab.id_a
  inner join  table_b b ON b.id = ab.id_b
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables, group by name and use `group_concat()` combined with `concat()`:

```
select concat(a.name, ' has ', group_concat(car separator ' and ')) col
from table_a a 
inner join table_ab ab on ab.id_a = a.id
inner join table_b b on ab.id_b = b.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2oVCVbxouRjwpwqpjZPFfL/0).
Results:

```
| col                   |
| --------------------- |
| tom has car1 and car2 |
| max has car1          |
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: But you accepted an answer that does not provide the results that you described.